# Why does my repeat function not work in grid property, in css?

Tags: css, grid-layout, css-grid

This code works fine:

```
grid: [row1-start] 'header header header header header' auto [row1-end]
    [row2-start] 'menu content content content content' auto [row2-end]
    [row3-start] 'footer footer footer footer footer' auto [row3-end] / 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

but when I use the `repeat()` function instead of the five `1fr`'s, it ruins my grids:

```
grid: [row1-start] 'header header header header header' auto [row1-end]
        [row2-start] 'menu content content content content' auto [row2-end]
        [row3-start] 'footer footer footer footer footer' auto [row3-end] / repeat(5, 1fr);
```

I have no problem using the function in `grid-template-columns` property, the problem happens when I want to use it in grid property.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation:

[image: doc image]

Full MDN reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template#explicit-track-list)

Answer (score 0):

## Formal Syntax

if you check the [formal syntax of grid-template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template#formal_syntax), you'll notice that grid template represents the columns by `<explicit-tract-list>` where as if you check the [formal syntax of grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns#formal_syntax), the columns are represented by `<track-list>`. If you look at the definition of `<explicit-track-list>` it has no `<track-repeat>` syntax, whereas `<track-list>` has it. This is indeed really annoying

## Solution in css?

There is no solution for this in css, except to use a css-prepropcessor as shown below

## Solution in Scss.

```scss
@function sass-repeat($times, $value) {
  $sequence: $value;
  @if $times == 0 {
    @return null;
  }
  @for $i from 1 to $times {
    $sequence: append($sequence, $value)
  }
  @return $sequence
}

// this can be used as 

.grid {
  grid-template: 
    "header header" 1fr
    "body body" 1fr
    / sass-repeat(2, 1fr);
}
```

#### Resulting CSS

```css
.grid {
  grid-template: "header header" 1fr "body body" 1fr/1fr 1fr;
}
```

#### Note:

you can save this function inside a file, and then import that function using `@use` in scss to use it everywhere